# HTTPS communication by URLLoader is not working fine on Galaxy nexus

Tags: apache-flex, https, flex4.5, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, air-android

I develop Air application of Android.
I try to run it on Galaxy Nexus.
But it's not working fine.

It's using HTTPS on URLLoader on the application.
But "Error #2032: Stream Error" is returned.

I try to run a same application on Nexus S Android 2.3.6 and Eee Pad Transformer Android 3.1.
These are working fine.

I think It's Adobe Air issue on Galaxy Nexus Android4.0.

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It work fine on Newest vesrion of "Adobe Air of Androis".